# How to start a GUI application in the background?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

How can I prevent a QApplication with a QMainWindow from stealing the keyboard focus when it starts? I'd like it to become active only after clicking on or alt-tabbing to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`showMinimized()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#showMinimized) instead of `show()` for you main window.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MainWindow w;
    w.showMinimized();

    return app.exec();
}
```